# Deleting matrix block on front end form

Tags: craft3, matrix

The below code doesn't appear to be working for me, it will delete all other blocks apart from itself. I just need it to delete itself.

`trophyOrders` is the Matrix field in the user account.

```
{% set orders = user.trophyOrders.all() %}

{# Loop through orders #}
{% for order in orders %}
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form-{{ order.id }}" class="f-left">
{{ csrfInput() }}
{{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
{{ redirectInput('account/manage-trophies?msg=entry-deleted') }}
{{ hiddenInput('userId', currentUser.id) }}
                                                        
{{ hiddenInput('fields[trophyOrders][sortOrder][]', order.id) }}
{{ hiddenInput('fields[trophyOrders][blocks][' ~ order.id ~'][type]', '0') }}

<button type="submit" class="btn-unstyled"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i></button>                          
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how that code is supposed to work. The `sortOrder` controls which blocks (both existing and new) get saved in what order. The input in your form includes *only* the ID of the current block in the loop, so it makes sense that all other blocks will be deleted.

You want to achieve the opposite – keep all blocks except the current block in the loop. So you need to output a `sortOrder` that includes all existing IDs *except* the current one.

This code should work:

```twig
{% set orders = user.trophyOrders.all() %}
{% set ids = orders|column('id') %}

{% for order in orders %}
    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        {{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('userId', currentUser.id) }}

        {% for id in ids|filter(id => id != order.id) %}
            {{ hiddenInput('fields[trophyOrders][sortOrder][]', id) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ hiddenInput('fields[trophyOrders][sortOrder][]', null) }}
        {% endfor %}

        <button type="submit" class="btn-unstyled">Delete order {{ order.id }}</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I added an else statement for when it's the last block, which seems to work. Thanks for your help, again.

`{% else %}             {{ hiddenInput('fields[trophyOrders][sortOrder][]', null ) }}`

Comment: @Mark Ah right, something like that would be required to remove the last matrix block, good catch!

Comment: I've added the `else` statement to my example code, in case someone is looking for a full example.